# WPF fake/ghost design time error

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, design-time

I have a strange behavior in VS2008 a few times: After some changes in a xaml file, **removing** a control with a compile time error, VS2008 keeps saying the error is still there, even when the control itself is not there anymore. I could only fix it by creating a new xaml file, copying the content and deleting the original file. I cleaned the solution, rebuild, restarted VS, restarted the computer and nothing exorcise this ghost error. The solution builds and runs successfully, but I can't see the design time editor.

Does anyone have faced this strange behavior before?
It would be really nice if I could find an easier way to workaround/avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not the answer you want, but you'll experience much greater WPF development performance if you can upgrade to VS2010. VS has improved so much it's almost listless. Plus if you try to run your app with 2010 and still have the same issue, there's another whole group of devs who could try to reproduce the error.

Comment: I agree. It's a matter of time for me to upgrade. I just wanted to know if this was a known issue of VS2008.